# Custom SessionRepositoryFilter creation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-session

We are using mongo persistance for HTTP sessions on Springboot project
and would like to avoid saving the Session on every call.
we have a default session expiry of 30 minutes
and would like to save the session access only on 5minute interval and not before

seems like the way is to extend SessionRepositoryFilter and use our own version

But how do we do this with existing SpringHttpSessionConfiguration